# Retrieve column values from table based on condition in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with three columns:

> (JobNo, ProgramId & Status)

`JobNo` have many `ProgramId` and each `ProgramId` has `Status`

I need to retrieve only those `JobNo` where all the `ProgramId` for the same `JobNo` have `Status` = "delivered".

From the given image only `JobNo` (1&4) should be output as only `JobNo` (1&4) the `ProgramId`'s `Status`="delivered".

[image: Click here to see table]

Comment: You should edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  The explanation is dense and hard to follow.

Comment: Please click on the above link to see the sample table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this (not tested):

```
SELECT      JobNo
FROM        MyTable
GROUP BY    JobNo
HAVING      SUM(IIF(Status = 'Delivered', 0 , 1)) = 0
```

Comment: Thanku sir.Got what i wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Your question suggests `group by` with `having`:

```
select jobid
from t
group by jobid
having min(status) = max(status) and min(status) = 'delivered';
```

Comment: Thanku sir.Got what i wanted.